# Web Service deployment into Glassfish error

Tags: glassfish

I am trying to deploy a simple; one java class hello world; web service into the Glassfish 4 Java EE server.

```
package sample;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloWorld {
    public String hello(String param){
    return param + ", World";
    }
}
```

But I get the following error. How do I fix it.

```
2015-10-15T10:18:19.397-0400|Severe: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
```

Here is the full exception stack trace I get.

```
2015-10-15T10:18:19.397-0400|Severe: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
2015-10-15T10:18:19.397-0400|Severe: Exception while deploying the app [WebServiceEx2MetroServer]
2015-10-15T10:18:19.397-0400|Severe: Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(name=, wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, portName=RegistrationPortTypeRPCPort, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationPortTypeRPC, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] of type [TYPE]
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(name=, wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, portName=RegistrationPortTypeRPCPort, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationPortTypeRPC, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] of type [TYPE]
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addWebComponentDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.connector.annotation.handlers.WebServiceHandler.processAnnotation(WebServiceHandler.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
    ... 59 more

2015-10-15T10:18:19.491-0400|Severe: Exception while deploying the app [WebServiceEx2MetroServer] : Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(name=, wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, portName=RegistrationPortTypeRPCPort, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationPortTypeRPC, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] of type [TYPE]
Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(name=, wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, portName=RegistrationPortTypeRPCPort, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationPortTypeRPC, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] of type [TYPE]
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortTypeRPCPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addWebComponentDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.connector.annotation.handlers.WebServiceHandler.processAnnotation(WebServiceHandler.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I realized that I had included Glassfish's run time libraries in my Maven configuration as provided libraries to assist with compiling the project. But somehow those Glassfish libraries were unexpectedly also getting deployed in my app's WEB-INF/lib. Once I took care of my Maven configuration to not include them into the deployment these errors went away.